# cannot find "App on facebook" section

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm following this tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

Under the "Configuring your app" section, I get to the following sentence: "Once you've created a Facebook app, select the "App on Facebook" section and specify a Canvas and Secure Canvas URL:"

At this stage, I'm totally stuck. I can't see the "App on Facebook" section whatsoever.

This is the screen I see after creating the app:
[image]

I apologise if I'm just being a dolt, but I didn't know what else to do!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry about the crappy tagging, but what on earth else could I have tagged this? If this is too elementary a question for this part of stack exchange, I'll accept that, but a recommendation as to where to move it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The setting you're looking for is on the first page of app settings - you're looking at the list of apps, not the settings for your app - click the 'Edit App' button to go into the app edit settings interface for that app

Comment: Er, and change your app secret immediately

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I click 'Edit App' nothing at all happens. It appears to reload the screen I'm already on! Also, if I choose 'Edit Settings', which I assume is the way to change my app secret, the exact same thing happens (nothing).

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue or a bug with the app settings interface - try clearing your browser cache and/or cookies - you should still be able to manually navigate to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP ID HERE>/summary/` which is the same place the 'edit app' link should go

Comment: Ok just tried clearing all browser cache/cookies etc. on both FF and Chrome, neither worked. Also, tried going to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/375968669161779/summary/ and got redirected to the screen in my screenshot :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't exist, because the section is missing. I've been looking for it for an hour. This image is not here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/fluid-canvas#configure